# LINQ query that calls some method for additional calculations

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I have a linq query that needs grouping on an id to count rows of 2 status values, then I would like to call a method that performs a calculation on the resulting counts. Perhaps someone can help me understand a better way to do this. When I run this I see an exception that the 'calcRate' is not recognized by linq, but I've done something similar before and it works fine. I may be approaching this incorrectly as well:

```
var query = from c in (context.table
    .Where(s => s.date >= startDate && s.date <= endDate)
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.id })
    .Select(s => new
        {
            id = h.Key.id,
            rate = calcRate(h.Count(s=>s.status == 1), h.Count(s=>s.status != 3))
        }).ToList())
        select new { id = c.id, rate = c.rate };
```

Comment: Unless you're doing aggregations (sums, groupings...), use linq-to-sql to query the DB and when you have your data on-hand, use linq-to-objects in your business layer to work with your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the part that the DB can do in the DB and then use `.AsEnumerable()` to bring the results back into .NET to finish the calculations.

```
var query = context.table
    .Where(s => s.date >= startDate && s.date <= endDate)
    .GroupBy(s => s.id)
    .Select(s => new
        {
            id = s.Key,
            rateArg1 = s.Count(s=>s.status == 1),
            rateArg2 = s.Count(s=>s.status != 3)
        })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => new { s.id, rate = calcRate(s.rateArg1, s.rateArg2)});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Gabe your code above solved one problem and created another for which I will need to so some other work. Still so much more to learn!

Answer (score 0):

your linq is correct but  part of your linq query that is before .ToList() is being converted to SQL by EF, and it doesnt know how to convert calcRate to SQL, you will have to do your calcRate after you fetch all the values from sql.